# React: updating property of object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that tracks documents as state, `aDocuments`.  When a button is clicked, the document is uploaded.  Each document object contains the functionality to handle the upload.  During the upload, a mode in the document is changed from new to uploading to done.  The document object updates the mode during the upload.  Each document is a reference from an object in the aDocuments array which is in my state.

How do I properly handle updating properties of an object in state, when that object can update itself?  My setState calls do nothing but cause a render.

```
Doc.prototype.upload = function (uploadComplete) {
  if (this.mode === 'new') {
    this.mode = 'uploading';
    // do uploading stuff and call uploadComplete after upload is finished
    $.ajax(..., complete: function() {
      this.mode = 'done';
      uploadComplete(this); 
    });
  }
}

// in my component
clickHandler: function (doc) {

  doc.upload(function(tmpDoc) {
    // this will cause render to show the doc as done
    this.setState('aDocuments', this.state.aDocuments);
  });

  // this will show the document as uploading
  this.setState('aDocuments', this.state.aDocuments);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `this.mode === 'uploading';` should probably be `this.mode = 'uploading';`

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  This isn't my actual code, just something I wrote to get the point across.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to update the state of the top-level component where your documents array lives, you need to pass a callback function via props (which modifies the top-level documents array) to the individual document components.

Comment: I am doing this.  It is the top-level component that gets the event that the user clicked the upload button.  Then that component calls the upload method on the document and that method changes the status of the document from new to uploading and then finally to done.  It just seems wrong that my document object is changing its own information while it shares a reference to the document object that is in my state.

Comment: @Brian I understand what you mean about it feeling 'wrong' but react lends itself to unilateral data flow and state is isolated within a component by design so you're pretty much left with callbacks like Mark said. If you want to tidy this up you could use spread attributes: 
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

Comment: There's also componentWillReceiveProps - I tend to (for better or worse) set certain incoming props to state as they're passed down. Not sure if that will help you here though.